# Why Can't I add a maker on the google map in the V3 API

Tags: api, google-maps, var

Why Can't I add a maker on the google map in the V3 API?
This is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
     var map;
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(100, 100); 
            function CoordMapType() {
            }

            CoordMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
            CoordMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 18;
            CoordMapType.prototype.minZoom = 10;


            CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
                var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = '<img name="" src="mapTiles/' + zoom + '/' + coord.y + '/' + coord.x + '.png"/>';
                div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
                div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
                div.style.fontSize = '10';
                return div;
            };


            CoordMapType.prototype.name = "Tile #s";
            CoordMapType.prototype.alt = "Tile Coordinate Map Type";

            var coordinateMapType = new CoordMapType();

            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: myCenter,
                    mapTypeControl:false
                    mapTypeId: "coordinate"
                 };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
              mapOptions);

                map.mapTypes.set('coordinate', coordinateMapType);
                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter, title: "Hello World!" });
                marker.setMap(map);  
            }

    </script>
```

I use the tiles in my server.The map can be displayed ,but the marker is not on the map.

What's the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `google.maps.LatLng` class supports latitude [-90, 90] and longitude [-180,180] so your `myCenter` object needs to be within that range.

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.88, -87.62);
```

[Google Maps API v3 LatLng Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

Excerpt from Google Maps API v3:
*Creates a LatLng object representing a geographic point. Latitude is specified in degrees within the range [-90, 90]. Longitude is specified in degrees within the range [-180, 180]. Set noWrap to true to enable values outside of this range. Note the ordering of latitude and longitude.*